# Does the SQS ApproximateNumberOfMessages attribute include the delayed and not visible messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm currently in the process of using SQS from AWS. Every 60 seconds my application pulls all of the messages off the queue and processes them. Given that I can only retrieve up to 10 messages in a single request, I want to query the queue for the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`. The aproximate number of messages in the queue determines how many times I need to call SQS in order to retrieve all of the messages in the queue.

When I query SQS for the queue attributes, I get:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '...',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Attributes: {
    QueueArn: 'arn:...',
    ApproximateNumberOfMessages: '0',           <--- helpful
    ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible: '0', <--- is this attribute included in the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`
    ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed: '0',    <--- is this attribute included in the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`
    CreatedTimestamp: '1641925448',
    LastModifiedTimestamp: '1641925448',
    VisibilityTimeout: '30',
    MaximumMessageSize: '262144',
    MessageRetentionPeriod: '345600',
    DelaySeconds: '90',
    RedrivePolicy: '{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:...","maxReceiveCount":4}',
    ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: '0',
    SqsManagedSseEnabled: 'false'
  }
}
```

As shown in the code block above, are `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible` and `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed` included in the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not included. [ApproximateNumberOfMessages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) is the number of messages currently available for retrieval:

> The number of messages available for **retrieval** from the queue.

Also for Standard queue, these values are approximate only, and may not represent actual numbers of messages present:

> For standard queues, the result is **approximate** because of the distributed architecture of Amazon SQS.

Comment: A related question: Are the three values mutually exclusive?